# SQL Server 2014/16 transaction replication

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql 2012 publisher(transaction) database. This publisher is good and working with other instance. When I try to create a subscriber from a sql 2016 named instance with a static PORT I'm having problem. I have created alias on both instances. Restarted SQL. I can use this alias from ssms from either server and works. 
When I create and add subscription instance it would not take the named instance with port. It takes only default\named not default\named,1234. not even alias. If I add server sp_addserver for either alias or default\named,1234 it says already exist. I also see error "Replication requires the actual server name to make a connection."

If I use default\named it will create subscription but it will keep retrying. distibutor to subscriber job will keep retrying. I see messages like "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server"

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, this error has been observed on a server that had been renamed after the original installation of SQL Server, and where the SQL Server configuration function ‘@@SERVERNAME’ still returned the original name of the server.

Can you run the below command and see if that's the same name you are  giving in subscription as well?

select @@SERVERNAME

If you see mismatch you can change it using

sp_addserver 'real-server-name', LOCAL

Comment: It returns default\named like I expected. When I run sp_helpserver on subscriber I see this and the publisher name. No alias name and I can't add it.

Comment: Replication uses NetBIOS which has a 20 character limit. Make sure your entire server name is less than 20

Comment: Did you check this link? It says about changing in host file. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/23ea8627-86a9-4cb7-bd48-ff3d1a5b4219/replication-and-alias-server-names?forum=sqlreplication

Comment: I think entire instance is is < 20. I have checked that blog about host name or cname. I made a cname too. I got this error too:  Agent message code 20084. The process could not connect to Subscriber default\named'.